# How to Change the color of status bar

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How can we change the color of the status bar? I know we can change the style by

```
[application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Something like `self.statusBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`?

Comment: Oh THAT type of Status Bar .. :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, you can, but it's a hack (and apple def. has another, better way of doing it that we don't have access to):
Set the status bar to black translucent and have a (sub)view with your wanted color as backgroundcolor directly behind it. That way you can get the effect of a different color, even with a gradient.
the frame for that would be `CGRectMake(0,0,320,20)`

Answer (score 14):

Just for information, for those who don't want to change view frames, setting window background will also work.

I wrote this in `AppDelegate`.

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.78f green:0.13f blue:0.11f alpha:1];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

Comment: This is a very easy way to change the 'status bar' color. +1

Comment: Please edit your answer and give space between `UIColor` and `colorWithRed`. I can't edit it because minimum six character is required.

Comment: not working when compiling with iOS7 and deployment target is iOS6.

Answer (score 4):

You can't select arbitrary colors for the iOS status bar. You can only choose between white, black opaque and translucent black.

Comment: I think there is so way for it... If you lock your iPhone screen with a screen password and try to enter a wrong password, color of the status bar changes to red.

Comment: That capability is most likely only available through a private API. Using private APIs is not allowed by Apple and would cause your app to be rejected from the App Store during review.

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```

Answer (score -3):

```
 self.window.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
```