# iPhone: Get default color of UIStatusBar

Tags: objective-c, ios4, background-color

How can I get the default color of the status bar (UIStatusBarStyleDefault) and use it as background color for my table view?

```
tableView.backgroundColor = ...?
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You only have two color choices for the status bar

`UIStatusBarStyleDefault` (gray) and `UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque` (black).

Try with

```
- [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated:NO];
```

Check the blog post for getting the background color

[Set Status Bar Color and Background](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/set-status-bar-color-and-background.html)

More on status bar.

[How to Change the color of status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456474/how-to-change-the-color-of-status-bar)

Comment: Thanks, maybe I'm missing something, but is there a way to retrieve the actual RGB color value of UIStatusBarsStyleDefault? Any other constant?

Comment: @Dan: I'm not sure and i think we do'nt have access to read the color value of status bar.